# can i use full text search on the view of a table

Tags: sql-server-2000

i am using sql server 2000 can i use full text search on the view of a table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SQL Server 2000 Full Text Search does **not** directly support Full Text Indexing of views. However, you can include Full Text queries *in* views, but not create Full Text Indexes *on* views in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: actually in my table the fulll text indexing is enabled is the full text queries "ll work on the view created by this table or not.......
pls give me the detailed explanation.........

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means?